# auto click in 'headless' server

Tags: java, automation, mouseevent, mousemove, mouse-coordinates

I had problem when I ran my code in server.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
public class AutoClicker {
    public static int rate = 5000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(rate);
                    robot.mouseMove(100, 100);
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        } catch (AWTException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

if I used remote desktop such as [remmina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remmina), then I run my code, it properly works.

But,

when I close remmina, my code suddenly 'pause' until I open my remmina again.

**Are there something that I missed to enable my code run in server 'headlessly'??**

Thanks, 
Ahmad

Comment: If you are running in a "headless" environment, what does it mean to move the mouse?

Comment: yeah, something like that, [fiji developer](http://fiji.sc/Fiji) has success to implement it, but I don't know which ones.